# Can a CPU "switches" between RealAddress / Protected / Virtual 8086 after OS has loaded?

Tags: x86, cpu-architecture

Can a CPU change it's working mode at "runtime (OS loaded)" or it is selected at booting time and after cannot be changed?
When a mode is selected, does the CPU actually reconfigure it's logic circuits internally or the modes are simply different software implementations done by the programmers?

Comment: You can change back to Real mode after switching to Protected mode.  If you set the segment limits while in Protected mode, it's called Unreal mode when you switch back.  https://wiki.osdev.org/Unreal_Mode.  Modes are hardware-supported, not *just* software.

Comment: On a side note: On the 286 switching into 16-bit protected mode was easily supported (similar to entering 32-bit protected mode from real mode). Intel didn't provide a CPU only mechanism to switch back to real mode. The solution was to reset the processor itself and have it reboot without destroying the contents of RAM and the BIOS providing a mechanism to help continue where an OS left of. You can imagine performance wasn't so great. This was resolved on 386+ processors.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Very interesting. I would have never thought about this mechanism

Answer (score 2):

The x86 CPU can switch between protected and real mode (virtual 8086 mode being sort of submode of the former), back and forth. There are documented sequences of operations (not just single instructions) that it needs to perform to change the current mode without going off the rails and locking up or resetting.

The CPU is essentially a large and complex finite state machine, so in a way it reconfigures as it changes its internal states. This may involve some changes in how it interacts with external devices at the signal level.

Comment: At present day, in which conditions is necessary to change mode at runtime. For a Windows10 system for example, are today programs that need to work in different mode? If Windows can talk to hardware, but programs only to windows, does windows itself switch between modes according to needs or generally this never happens, and the modes are just a way to preserve compatibility?

Comment: @Paolo The CPU starts in real mode (just as 40 years ago when it was the only mode). Windows does not need to switch back to real mode these days. In some rare cases (e.g. when there's no suitable video driver), it avoids doing so and instead emulates realmode code (of the video BIOS) while staying in protected mode. Mode switches are expensive and inconvenient as they affect operation of nearly everything. Note also, virtual 8086 mode is not immediately accessible once the CPU is in 64-bit/long mode, and so it's normally not used either these days.

Comment: @Paolo New modes have been usually introduced while retaining old modes, because of compatibility. But it's not always done that way for various reasons. E.g. MSDOS is dead as a profitable product and Microsoft isn't interested investing in Windows compatibility with DOS programs. Hence, there's no big need for real or virtual 8086 mode anymore. So, folks at AMD and Intel decided it was OK not to make 64-bit/long mode compatible with it. And it's similar with UEFI as BIOS replacement. UEFI boots your OS already in protected mode (32-bit or 64-bit).

Comment: @Paolo: x86-64 OSes run 32-bit user-space processes in "compat" mode, but run the kernel and 64-bit processes in long mode.  compat is kind of a sub-mode of long mode, designed to be easy to use this way.  (Interrupts come back to the kernel in 64-bit long mode, for example.)  Other modes like Real Mode are *not* like that; interrupt handlers would run in Real Mode, and is unusable for user-space processes because it doesn't support memory protection or a reduced privilege level.